# Multiple rows into single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have a below data in the table.

[image]

Need output like below.

[image]

I have tried the below logic but in my case, those Item# columns are NVARCHAR type, so the MAX aggregate function is giving unknown as a result.

```
SELECT ID, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5
FROM(
SELECT ID, MAX(Item1), MAX(Item2), MAX(Item3), MAX(Item4), MAX(Item5)
FROM Sample_Table WITH(NOLOCK)
) A
WHERE A.ID = '0001_11'
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Please help me to get this result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post data instead of images

Comment: I think you mean `text` rather than "data" @Chanukya. Those images are *"data"*. :)

Comment: Do you *really* have the strings `'unknown'` in your column that looks like a `int`? If so, `'unknown'` has a "greater" value than `'7622'`; which would explain why maybe you're not getting the results you're after.

Comment: @Larnu, yes we have a strings 'unknown'  and it is a nvarchar type, not an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using pivot logic.  In this case, we want to disregard the value `Unknown`, so the `CASE` expressions below assign it to `NULL`, which is ignored by `SUM`.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Item1 = 'Unknown' THEN NULL ELSE Item1 END) AS Item1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Item2 = 'Unknown' THEN NULL ELSE Item2 END) AS Item2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Item3 = 'Unknown' THEN NULL ELSE Item3 END) AS Item3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Item4 = 'Unknown' THEN NULL ELSE Item4 END) AS Item4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Item5 = 'Unknown' THEN NULL ELSE Item5 END) AS Item5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Item6 = 'Unknown' THEN NULL ELSE Item6 END) AS Item6
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim Biegeleisen. Working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Use TRY_CAST to cast the values to numbers. TRY_CAST returns NULL if the value cannot be converted.

```
SELECT ID,
    MAX(TRY_CAST(Item1 as INT)) AS Item1,
    MAX(TRY_CAST(Item2 as INT)) AS Item2,
    MAX(TRY_CAST(Item3 as INT)) AS Item3,
    MAX(TRY_CAST(Item4 as INT)) AS Item4,
    MAX(TRY_CAST(Item5 as INT)) AS Item5,
    MAX(TRY_CAST(Item6 as INT)) AS Item6
FROM Sample_Table WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY ID;
```